# Can I debug web2py with pdb in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, web2py, pdb

In my Emacs, I started *pdb* with:

- <kbd>Alt-x</kbd>
- sudo pdb web2py.py --options values *(I am already at web2py directory)*

After this, I can see the *pdb* shell in my Emacs, and list the code. Then I setup the breakpoint with **b** command, and continue with **c**.

My web application started and working, but the breakpoint is not effective. I tried to set many breakpoints, in different syntax region, and I am sure everyone of them can be hit.

I even tried to use *pdb* directly from the shell, but still does not work. I think maybe there're some tricky some I should setup for *pdb* to work with *web2py*. But I can't figure it out.

#### Update

I tried to debug the `web2py.py` file, and it worked. So I guess the problem is caused by how *web2py* dynamically load other modules...But I found other posts saying that *Eclipse* and many other debuger works well with *web2py*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up the breakpoint approach.

I found inserting

```
 import pdb

 pdb.set_trace()
```

works very well, though not as convenient as setting breakpoint.